# Redirect query string URLs with varying values to new URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**I need to permanently redirect requests for a page with query strings to a new page**, so that:

`http://www.example.com/photos/showimage.php?id=148`
or
`http://www.example.com/photos/showimage.php?id=148&p=5`

... will become redirected to:

`http://www.example.com/photos/`

The "id" parameter will always be requested, though the "p" parameter will only sometimes be requested.

The "id" and "p" values at the end of the query string could be any integer.

I also need to redirect ones like these:

`http://www.example.com/photos/showcat.php?category=Exhibition%252BImages%25`

... to the same URL:

`http://www.example.com/photos/`

The value at the end of this query string could be anything.

I've looked at various examples for this type of redirect but they all seem to deal with specific forms that don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^photos/showimage\.php$ /photos? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)category=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^photos/showcat\.php$ /photos? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Wow.  I was trying all sorts last night until eventually I gave up, but that works like a charm.  Thank you so much!